# Language characters showing as question mark boxes

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I the following text (used for testing):

> ```
> TÄSTåÄ
> ```

It's showing on the page as:

> T�ST��

I have utf-8 as my content-type:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I'm using font-family:

> "lucida
>   grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif

Any idea why thse characters won't show up properly?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste the text with the boxes from the browser into an application that you know can display the test text correctly, like the editor you used to prepare it? (You could use Word, but use the paste option for text only.) If the original text shows up then you have a font problem. Otherwise you have an encoding problem somewhere before the text gets to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the file is being saved as a UTF-8 encoded file and not as plain text.

Comment: Hm, It's a php file, being saved through dreamweaver, don't think its plain text.

Comment: @dave True UTF-8 is a default document setting for PHP files in Dreamweaver but it can be changed.  Also note what your unicode normalization and BOM settings are.  With UTF-8 you should not need a BOM.  Good to check the basics... see http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/dreamweaver/mx2004/dwusing_errata/dwusing_errata2.html

Comment: Thank you.  I've checked all settings, it's set to UTF-8 though and BOM is unchecked.

Comment: @dave - The only way to really be sure is to check the byte sequence in the saved file, e.g. using xxd on a *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

Pls make sure you saved file in 'UTF-8' or 'utf-8 without BOM'.  If you used UTF-8 only for encoding your html page, please check the DOCTYPE is valid.